# Skip Row in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase

```
"news" : {
    "-KnLRSIOyD7HgldFGty" : {
      "caption" : "some grounds",
      "content" : "some contents",
      "created_on" : 1498246403444,
      "newspaper_id" : "-KnLPu2N5039ZbqS",
      "status" : false,
      "thumbnail" : "thumbnail/1498254125498",
    },
}


"newspapers" : {
    "-KnLRSIOyD7HgldFGty" : {
      "logo" : "logo/1498245996906",
      "paper_name" : "NewsOnline"
      },
}
```

I want to filter firebase to do something like this.
`mDatabaseRef.child("news").orderByChild("newspaper_id").equalTo(id).orderByChild("status").equalTo(false);`
Since multiple orderBy() will throw exception in firebase, what is the other way to achieve the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Firebase supports only a single orderBy per query.

So if you want to filter or order the results on more than one property (2 query in your case), you'll either have to do the additional filtering (or ordering) client-side in your Android code or you'll have to come up with your own indexing scheme that combines the properties.

In your case i suggest you add a new child named `newspaperId_status` which can get the value as concatenation of both values like this:

```
newspaperId_status: -KnLPu2N5039ZbqS_false
```

In this way you can query all newspappers which have the status of `false`.

Hope it helps.